# Twitter Bootstrap Rails - how can I separate my styles from bootstrap_and_overrides.less

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, twitter-bootstrap, less

I'm using the `twitter-bootstrap-rails` gem for styles in my app.

At the moment, I'm writing all my style ruls inside `bootstrap_and_overrides.css.less`, and this turns messy and redundant as the application grows.

I'd like to split the less code to smaller files that will be required on a per page basis,  but still be able to use the bootstrap colors and mixins. I found that after I split it into another file, I couldn't use these components anymore. I guess I'm probably not including it correctly or in the proper order - thoughts? thanks.

Answer (score 0):

look at https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/blob/master/less/bootstrap.less

you should be able to use `@import "override-forms.less"` in your `bootstrap_and_overrides.css.less` for example.

Comment: for some reason it not seeing bootstrap's mixings :(

Comment: ok, looks like it only works if application (top) manifest is also .less